# Prime Factors of $a+b$

Tags: number-theory

If $a = p_{a_1}^{\alpha_1}·p_{a_2}^{\alpha_2}··· p_{a_k}^{\alpha_k}$ and $b =p_{b_1}^{\beta_1}·p_{b_2}^{\beta_2}··· p_{b_k}^{\beta_k}$ then what can be the possible prime factors of $a+b$ ?

I know a specific case for this question: If the least prime factor of $a$ is $p$ and that of $b$ is $q$ where $p,q>2$ then the least prime factor of $a±b$ is $2$. The explanation is very simple. Since both $a$ and $b$ are odd hence their sum or difference must be even.

My approach:

Let $d = gcd(a,b) \Rightarrow a+b = d(a' +b')$ where $gcd(a',b') = 1$. Clearly the factors of $d$ will also be the factors of $a+b$ but that is not the only factor because from parity checking we can tell whether $2$ is a factor of $a+b$.How can we extend this "checking" to other primes as well?

Context of the problem:

This question is derived from this:

> The number of positive integers n for which $3n-4$,$4n-5$ and $5n-3$ are all primes is

My approach:

From the concept of 'factoring' we tell that $n$ cannot be of the form $4k$,$5k$,$3k$. Now, if we take $n =2$ we get the required solution. The reason that it is the only solution comes from parity concept. Any number of the form $4k$ can be written in the form $2k$ for $k≥2$. So as per the condition , n cannot take even values , so n is odd which implies that $5n$ is odd and $5n-3$ is even which cannot be prime since the only even prime is 2. My question is how can I judge whether $4n-5$ is composite for odd values of n? $4n-5$ is clearly odd and so it doesn't have 2 as its factor. But how can I show that there may / may not exist some other prime factor?

Comment: In general, prime factors of $a$ and $b$ are not helpful for the prime factors of $a+b$. Even if, say, $a=2^n$ has a lot of prime factors $2$, $2^n-1$ may only have one prime factor.

Comment: The ABC conjecture is about this.

Comment: The general case is covered by the wide open Schinzel hypothesis. The most famous special case of this is the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: The prime factors dividing exactly one of $a,b$ can be ruled out for $a+b$, the common prime factors of $a,b$ will ocuur in $a+b$. Primes that divide neither $a$ nor $b$ can divide the sum or not. Note that efficient factoring of $a+b$ given the factorizations of $a$ and $b$ would enable efficient factoring of every positive integer, which is assumed to be impossible.

Comment: For the below problem , you only need to show that NOT ALL numbers can be prime simultaneously (for $n>2$) , nothing more is claimed.

Comment: Whether $4n-5$ is composite cannot be judged in general. Infinite many numbers of this form are prime (Dirichlet).

Comment: @Peter Composite values of $4n-5$ can be found out like this: $f(n) = 4n-5$ at $n=7$, $f(7) = 23$ which is prime, so $f(7+23 = 30) = 115$ is composite. This is restating of the fact that no algebraic expression can describe a prime number.

Comment: @SDas What I mean is that without further informations for $n$, we cannot know whether $4n-5$ is composite, of course this expression is composite for infinite many positive integers $n$ (the easiest case is that $n$ is a multiple of $5$) but also prime for infinite many positive integers $n$.